# Переход в другую activity после получения permissions

Tags: android, permissions

При запуске приложения показываем стартовый экран и там же происходит запрос разрешения на чтение/запись SD Card. Со стартовой activity через 2 сек идет переход на другую activity. Пользователь не успевает прочитать запрос на разрешение и диалог остается висеть "за" приложением. Подскажите, как сделать переход в другую activity после обработки диалога запроса на разрешения? Или как вывести диалог запроса на передний фон.
Вот код activity:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> urlsFromServer = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Uri> filesPath = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean CheckFileStorage = false;
    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private String fileNamePath = "filesPath.json";

    private String urlServerJson = "http://*****.ru/todbook/booklist.json";

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        new ParseJsonServer().execute();
    }

    private class ParseJsonServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJsonServer = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlServerJson);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJsonServer = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return resultJsonServer;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {


            if (resultJsonServer != "") {
                urlsFromServer = GetListUrlCovers(resultJsonServer);

            } else {
                CheckListFile(fileNamePath);
                if (!CheckFileStorage) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.NoInternetText), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    NextActivity();

                } else {
                    NextActivity();
                }
            }

            CheckListFile(fileNamePath);

            if (CheckFileStorage) {

                String jsResult = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileNamePath);
                filesPath = getFilesPathFromFile(jsResult);

            } else {

                filesPath = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < urlsFromServer.size(); i++) {
                    int d = i + 1;
                    String fileUrl = urlsFromServer.get(i);
                    String filenam = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + File.separator + "bookcover_" + d + ".jpg";
                    FileLoader(fileUrl, filenam);
                }
                String strJs = new Gson().toJson(filesPath);

                if (!checkPermissions()) {
//                    Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Разрешения уже получены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setPermissions();
                }

                MyJSON.saveData(getApplicationContext(), strJs, fileNamePath);
            }

            if (filesPath.size() == urlsFromServer.size()) {

                NextActivity();

            } else {
                try {
                    deleteFile(fileNamePath);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < urlsFromServer.size(); i++) {
                    int d = i + 1;
                    String fileUrl = urlsFromServer.get(i);
                    String filenam = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + File.separator + "bookcover_" + d + ".jpg";
                    FileLoader(fileUrl, filenam);
                }
                String strJs = new Gson().toJson(filesPath);

                if (!checkPermissions()) {
                    setPermissions();
//                    Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Разрешения уже получены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
/*
                else {
                    setPermissions();
                }
*/

                MyJSON.saveData(getApplicationContext(), strJs, fileNamePath);
                NextActivity();
            }
        }

    }

    private ArrayList<String> GetListUrlCovers(String strJson) {

        JSONObject dataJsonObj;

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray books = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("books");

            for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject book = books.getJSONObject(i);
                String url_book = book.getString("coverUrl");
                urlsFromServer.add(url_book);// пишу урлы в ArrayList
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urlsFromServer;
    }

    private void CheckListFile(String fileNameStorage) {
        File fileUrls = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileNameStorage);

        if (fileUrls.exists()) {

            CheckFileStorage = true;

        }

    }

    private void FileLoader(String fileUrl, String filename) {

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            setPermissions();
//            Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Разрешения уже получены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
/*
        else {
            setPermissions();
        }
*/

        ThinDownloadManager downloadManager = new ThinDownloadManager(5); //количество потоков загрузки
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(fileUrl);
        Uri destinationUri = Uri.parse(filename);
        DownloadRequest downloadRequest = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri).setDestinationURI(destinationUri);
        downloadManager.add(downloadRequest);
        filesPath.add(destinationUri);
    }

    private ArrayList<Uri> getFilesPathFromFile(String jsResult) {
        ArrayList<Uri> urisImg = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray rootJson = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(jsResult));
            for (int i = 0; i < rootJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject o = rootJson.getJSONObject(i);
                String strTo = (String) o.get("uriString");
                urisImg.add(Uri.parse(strTo));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urisImg;
    }

    private void NextActivity() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }
        boolean isGranted = true;
        for (int result : grantResults) {
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                isGranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isGranted) {
            Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Разрешения получены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "В разрешениях отказано", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void setPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

}
```

Comment: запускайте асинк таск после того как человек дал пермишны)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `WelcomeActivity` в  `onCreate`  пишите

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Если используете библиотеку поддержи -  AppCompatActivity , а вы ее используете, проверять апи не нужно. Так же можно не проверять есть ли уже разрешение, т.е. метод checkSelfPermission можно не использовать. Запрашиваете разрешение, если оно уже было ранее получено, ничего страшного не произойдет.

Далее в классе WelcomeActivity добавляете этот метод

```
       @Override
        public  void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        new ParseJsonServer().execute();
                    }
                   else {  Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Без данного разрешения приложение не сможет хранить полученные данные и не будет работать, пожалуйста дайте разрешение", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);

                  } 
                }
            }
        }
```

Toast, который вызывается в случае отказа  будет быстро исчезать(его не успеют прочитать)  , т.к. после него идет повторный запрос на разрешение.  Так что такая реализация не очень красива. Но вы должны понять, что после получения разрешения , требуемый код должен вызываться именно отсюда.

И вообще лучше бы прочитали [документацию](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?#perm-request) , даже с гугл переводом, там всё очень понятно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает. Почитаю, разберусь